# No option for free/shared service plan

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

When I create a web app in aure there is an option to select  service plan.  I want to use the free or shared plan for development purposes but it does not give these options in the dev / test tab.

[image]

It only gives basic tier options.

Microsoft say they have a free and shared tier but there is no option to create a service plan for it.  How do you create a service plan for the free and shared tiers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue just a few days ago. Please ensure that `OS` selected is `Windows` and not `Linux` when you create the WebApp (default is Linux when creating a new WebAp) and you should see free tier when creating a new App Service Plan.

Comment: I have linux selected, there is no free tier option as shown in screenshot

Comment: I don't think `Free` tier is offered when you choose `Linux`. From the pricing page (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/app-service/linux/), only Basic, Standard, Premium and Isolated plans are available for Linux OS.

Comment: I second this answer